# Unusual categorization of slang terms in parts of speech ("cap")

Tags: syntax, english, american-english, slang, aave

I am not educated in syntax (or any formal linguistics really), so my hypotheses and observations in this question may not be super high-level.

I am a young American English speaker from the Midwest. I've noticed an interesting phenomenon with slang terms used among my generation, particularly the word "cap." This word, in its current vernacular usage, does not seem to neatly fall into any specific grammatical category or part of speech. Here are some examples of its complexity:

1. The word is often described to older people who do not use it as a synonym for the noun "lie." Indeed, the common sentence "No cap!" suggests that the term is being used like a noun, and I think teenagers today think of it that way. If "cap" is a noun, it is a unique, uncountable noun.
2. In some sense, the word can be considered more like an adjective. Another common phrase is "That's cap." In that sentence, "cap" appears to be a predicate adjective modifying "that."
3. Finally, the term can absolutely be a verb. When someone isn't telling the truth, one can say they are "capping." I think this might have been the original usage of the term, but I have not done enough research to know that for certain.

I don't feel like we have many words which are standard parts of the lexicon and can be used for in many grammatical categories. Thus, I wonder if there is something special about slang terminology which makes it likely to have a muddy variety of grammatical functions before it becomes standardized or falls into disuse. My tentative prediction is that since young speakers only hear new slang words from other young speakers, and because the terms have not yet adopted a function which speakers consider "proper," young speakers are free to use them in new and disparate ways that aren't considered any more "wrong" than the rest. Alternatively, the grammar of this specific term could be explained by non-Black speakers (I believe the term originated in urban Black communities) adopting an AAVE term which clashes with their non-AAVE grammar.

Is it common for slang terms to occupy multiple parts of speech? How and why does this arise? I would appreciate examples from other languages.

Comment: *no* + verb occurs in the famous Reggae line *No woman no cry* meaning "Woman, don't cry". This is of course Jamaican vernacular English but it may have parallels in AAVE.

Comment: On the contrary, we have many words (usually short ones) which are used in multiple functional categories. But your observation about how people learn new words is correct: that is the **normal** process by which people learn their native language(s). Nobody consciously knows their grammar, unless they have been taught it, or thought very hard about it.

Comment: It’s not **that** uncommon for a word to be both noun, adjective(-ish) and verb. There’s even a different slangish term with the same meaning ‘lie’ that fits the bill: we can say “no shit”, “that’s (bull)shit” and “I shit you not”. Note that when we say ‘that’s (bull)shit’, the _(bull)shit_ is still a noun – we can modify it with _such_, but not _so_ (‘that’s such bullshit’, but not ‘*that’s so bullshit’). However, as a true adjective, _shit_ means ‘of poor quality’, and ‘that’s (so) shit’ works fine too. I’m only vaguely familiar with _cap_, but my feeling is you’d say ‘that’s such cap’ too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the comment. I don't think I've ever heard "That's such cap" before (certainly not as common as "No cap" and "That's cap"), but I could imagine it as a possibility.

Comment: @GrahamH. No, I haven’t either. I was running out of characters in my previous comment; what I meant to say was that it sounds more likely to me to use _such_ than to say, “That’s so cap” (i.e., it behaves like a noun just like ‘(bull)shit’). Even though it’s not a term I’m very familiar with, it ‘feels’ more like a noun than an adjective here. I’ve also never heard it used attributively, and I don’t really know whether it would work at all (“?That’s such a cap thing to say”).

Comment: Just because one word can be used in a context where most words of a category can, does not rule out the possibility of it being part of that category. Also, I do think I have heard "so" being used before "bull****" before, but I cannot say for certain. Further, I feel like there is a possibility of the original form being "That's *a* cap.", with elision of the "a", which would mean that it doesn't truly act as an adjective, because as far as I have heard it being used, that is the only phrase where it could be considered to be an adjective.

Comment: In "that's cap," would you modify it adverbially ("that's very cap") or adjectivally ("that's some serious cap")?

Comment: @alphabet I guess neither… or maybe both? I’m not sure. Both of those sentences seem a bit improbable. Tentatively, I guess the first option seems very slightly more likely.